# Notification does not open correct activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging and I have my own class that extends `FirebaseMessagingService`.
My activities order are as follows:
`SplashActivity` -> `MainActivity` -> `DetailsActivity` . When the app is in the `MainActivity` and I send a message using the Firebase Console everything is fine it opens up the `Dialog` I wanted it to open. Also when I am in `MainActivity` and I send a message that is meant to open `DetailsActivity` everything is fine.
However when the app is in the background and I send the message, the `Notification` does not show as intended and when I click it it opens `SplashActivity` first even though the defined `Intent` to be opened using `PendingIntent` is `MainActivity`. How can I go about these two problems?

In my custom `FirebaseMessagingService` class I have defined the Intent to have the following flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and my PendingIntent to have the following flags `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if method **onMessageReceived** in your **FirebaseMessagingServise** is properly called in background, so you can setup what you need.

I had to send **data message** type instead of **notification**, because when you send type notification then method OnMessageReceived is not called in background and firebase handles push notification instead of you. Be aware **you cannot** even combine type notification and data message.

More about data message you can find here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: the onMessageReceived is not called when app is in background only in foreground,how do u get it called in background?

Comment: you have to send data message instead of notification. Difference between these two types you can find on the link I sent to you in answer. Shortly said you have to rename in json **notification** parameter to **data**

Comment: wow...this totally sucks,was avoiding implementing server at all cost. thanks though